# Drag and drop to get path of file

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Here is an example that I cannot get to work. I followed the directions, but when I try to drag and drop a file to the form, it doesn't let me, and gives me the Unavailable cursor.

It's quite easy. Just enable `drap-and-drop` by setting the `AllowDrop` property to True and handle the DragEnter and DragDrop events. In the `DragEnter` event handler, you can check if the data is of the type you want using the DataFormats class. In the `DragDrop` event handler, use the Data property of the `DataEventArgs` to receive the actual data.

Example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, _
                       e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.AllowDrop = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, _
                           e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) _
  Handles Me.DragDrop

    Dim files() As String = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
    For Each path In files
        MsgBox(path)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, _
                            e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) _
  Handles Me.DragEnter

    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.AllowDrop = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop
        Dim theFiles() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData("FileDrop", True), String())
        For Each theFile As String In theFiles
            MsgBox(theFile)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_DragEnter(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but I still cannot figure it out.  I am new to vb.net, where do these 2 lines of code go?  BTW, I am just trying to drop a file onto the actual form, there are no other controls on the form.

Comment: Updated answer check now and let me know.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I think it is almost working, but it says that Path is not declared.  I tried to Dim Path as String and it wouldn't let me.  Thank you for you help!

Comment: You need to import path as Imports System.IO as you can see in my edit

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you, but it says 'DragEnter' is not a member of the 'System.IO.Path'

Comment: It's Ok no problem.Leave that apart I have updated my answer have you seen that..If not see it and simply copy and paste it in your form and click F5 to run the form and try to drag and drop any text file and you'll indeed get an alert.

Comment: I copied and pasted, and there are no errors, and Form1 comes up, but when I drag something to it, it still gives me the Unavailable cursor.

Comment: Try to create a new VS project and do it once again and let me know if you get the same error.

Comment: Perfect, it is working now!  Thank you, I have spent about 8 hours on this.

Comment: you're welcome...Glad that helped you and you can mark it as an answer so that it will be closed :)

Comment: Just curious, why did it work after I created a new project?  I had just created a new project.